# Using lightning-combobox is breaking LWR app

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-base-component, lightning-web-runtime

I am using node v16.15.0 in a project using LWR outside salesforce. I have done the steps to add the base components and the lightning design system design. lightning-button and lightning-spinner are working perfectly.

When I add lightning-combobox to the app html template however, whole page breaks and nothing is displayed. There is no error diplayed in npm run dev output. In developer console the errors that show are some imports failing (which don't happen if I remove the combobox from page):

[image: Developer console error]

When checking all the network requests, it would seem the issue is that it is trying to retrieve the wrong url. One of those errors come from trying to fetch `http://localhost:3000/1/module/esm/0/l/en-US/mi/lightning%2FinternationalizationLibrary%23datetime%5CdateTimeUtils%2Fv%2F1_19_1-alpha/s/fa776e409ac8ee252f4635dffd0472f7/lightning_internationalizationLibrary_datetime/dateTimeUtils.js`

but I can see that there is a similar successful fetch with the url `http://localhost:3000/1/module/esm/0/l/en-US/mi/lightning%2FinternationalizationLibrary%23datetime%2FdateTimeUtils%2Fv%2F1_19_1-alpha/s/fa776e409ac8ee252f4635dffd0472f7/lightning_internationalizationLibrary_datetime_dateTimeUtils.js`

So something for some reason is using %5C instead of %2F and / instead of _

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@salesforce-ux/design-system": "^2.21.5",
    "lightning-base-components": "^1.19.1-alpha",
    "lwc": "2.38.1",
    "lwr": "0.9.5"
 }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, fixed my issue editing the following files:

node_modules@lwrjs\module-registry\build\es\linker\linker.js

after

```
let link = strategy(importRef, runtimeEnvironment, runtimeParams, signature);
// replace all locations of importee with the link
```

I added

```
if (link.includes('\\utils') || link.includes('lightning_iconSvgTemplatesUtility')) {
    link = link.replaceAll('\\', '#');
}
```

node_modules@lwrjs\module-registry\build\es\index.js

in `resolveModuleUriSync` function I added:

```
if (moduleId.specifier.includes('#')) {
    return uri.replaceAll('\\', '_');
}
```